# Crystal Subreport Formatting Issues

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

[image]When I drill down to a subreport, a text field in aqua "Description" is overlapping another text field. When I check the "Can Grow" checkbox it does not change that subreport, but it changes the next subreport when I click on the text field "Description". What is going on here?

Comment: Is the text field "ABC" in the same section as the subreport?

Comment: I believe so. When I click on ABC it drills down to another view/report but when I look at the report explorer it is not listed as a subreport.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have your subreport and your text field "ABC" in the same section.  When "Can Grow" is enabled on an object, such as a SubReport, it will grow as much as is needed to display all of its data, however, it won't reposition other fields around it unless they are in a different section.

Create a new section by right-clicking on the section label located to the left of the section in your designer.  Each section label should be named something like "Details" or "Group Header" or "Page Footer".  Right-click the label that corresponds to the section where your subreport is located within, then choose "Insert Section Below".  If you were to do this on the "Details" section it will create a second section that should now be labeled "Details b" and the original section label will update to "Details a".  Your subreport will remain in the "Details a" section and you will want to move the Text Field "ABC" down to the "Details b" section.

Once this is done, the subreport will grow as needed within its section and the section will grow with it, then the following Details b section will print below it and should no longer be over-lapped by the subreport.

Comment: When I click on the text field ABC, it takes me to another report or subreport I guess. However, that subreport doesn't exist in the report explorer. That is the field I am having trouble with formatting. It doesn't format when it is first displayed, but when I click on the text field ABC, it is displayed correctly as I adjusted it. I tried moving the field to another line but they are overlapping horizontally rather than vertically.

Comment: Would you be able to link an image of your report in the designer view?  You can edit your original question and add the link at the end of the question.

Comment: Yes, I just added it.